# Protecting numpy attributes using setters and getters in Python

Tags: python, numpy, attributes, private

I have run into an issue with protecting my attribute, a numpy array. I think that I understand why the issue appears, but I'm not sure on the way to prevent it from happening. Especially because my code will be used by relatively inexperienced programmers.

**In Short:**, I have a class with an attribute that I want to ensure some properties of. For that purpose I use a private internal variable and getters and setters. However, not everything goes the way I want it to, the protection does not work when a slice of the atribute is set.

**In Detail:** Here is the first part of the MWE:

```py
# Importing modules.
import numpy as np


class OurClass(object):
    """
    The class with an attribute that we want to protect.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
        The number of random numbers in the attribute.

    Attributes
    ----------
    our_attribute : array
        The attribute that contains `n` random numbers between 0 and 1, will never be smaller than zero.
    _our_attribute : array
        The protected attributed that ensures that `our_attribute` is never smaller then zero.
        (Normally I don't list this)
    """
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.our_attribute = np.random.random(n)

    @property
    def our_attribute(self):
        return self._our_attribute

    @our_attribute.setter
    def our_attribute(self, value):
        """
        When the attribute is set, every entry needs to be larger then zero.

        Parameters
        ----------
        value : array
            The array that should replace our_attribute.
        """
        print("Setter function is used")
        self._our_attribute = np.clip(value, 0, np.inf)
```

Now when I'm setting and getting `our_attribute` it should be protected, see the following examples:

```py
# Lets create our object.
print('Create object:')
num = 5
our_object = OurClass(num)
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute, '\n')

# Lets replace the setter function te verify that it works.
print('Change object:')
our_object.our_attribute = np.linspace(-5, 20, num)
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute, '\n')

# Now modify the attribute using basic functions.
print('Modify using numpy functionality:')
our_object.our_attribute = our_object.our_attribute - 5
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute, '\n')
```

However, the moment that I'm working on a slice (view) of the attribute, weird stuff happens.

```py
# Now modify a slice of the attribute, we can do this because it is a numpy array.
print('Modify a slice of the attribute.')
our_object.our_attribute[0] = -5
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute)
```

The following things happened:

1. It calls the getter function twice, (once for `our_object.our_attribute[0]` and once in the `print`)
2. The attribute seems unprotected as a negative number appears.
3. Even the private attribute seems unprotected as

```py
print('  even the private _our_attribute:', our_object._our_attribute, '\n')
```

includes negative numbers as well!

**My speculation:**

2. A slice of the attribute is not protected because we access it does not go into the setter function. Numpy allows us to directly access the slice and change the content. (We obtain `our_attribute` from the getter function, now we act directly upon this array object, which allows the setting of a slice, which is handled by Numpy, not our class as the object that we're acting upon is now simply an array.
3. The getter function includes `return self._our_attribute` which is NOT a copy action, now both `self.our_attribute` and `self._our_attribute` point to the same location. If you change any of the two in place the other changes as well, hence we end up with a change in our private attribute even though we didn't intent to change it.

**Now my Questions:**

1. Are my speculations correct, or did I make a mistake.
2. I assume that I can define the setter differently to ensure that the private attribute becomes separate from the public one:

```
@property
def our_attribute(self):
    return np.copy(self._our_attribute)
```

but now setting a slice will simply not change anything.

**How do I properly protect my attribute in a way that I can change a slice of the attribute and still retain the protection. It is important that this protection is not visible from the outside, as to not confuse my students.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your speculations are essentially correct.  There is no such thing in Python as "protecting" a mutable object from modification, and NumPy arrays are mutable.  You could do the exact same thing with plain Python lists:

```
@property
def my_list(self):
    return self._my_list  # = [1, 2, 3, 4]

@my_list.setter
def my_list(self, value):
    self._my_list = [float('inf') if x < 0 else x for x in value]
```

It's not exactly clear to me what you want here, but if you want the numpy array returned by your attribute to be immutable you could set `array.setflags(write=False)` on the array.  This will also make slices of the array immutable so long as the slices are created after setting the write=False flag.

However, if you want some kind of magically bounded NumPy array, where any operation on the array will enforce the bounds you've set, this is possible with an ndarray subclass, but non-trivial.

Still, none of these options would prevent someone from just re-casting the underlying data to a mutable array.

The only way to completely protect the underlying data is to use a read-only mmap as the underlying array buffer.

But TL;DR there is nothing magical about accessing a Python object through `property` that can make that object immutable.  If you really want an immutable data type you have to use an immutable data type.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I was afraid of this. I'll use an immutable type then. But indeed I had my hopes set upon an 'magical NumPy feature', as for the real code it did make sense to change only some parts of the attributes. You still can do that to an immutable, but it would be more work, lets say you want to change the attribute of immutable type: 1. copy it and 2. recast the copy into the a mutable type 3. change part of the mutable object 4. recast it into the immutable type, 5. set attribute with the immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank @Iguananaut for her clear answer. Here I only want to implement her answer in the example that I showed before. And yes, this is still not really protected, but this should prevent issues, unless people start messing around with the internal variables.

I decided to go the route with `array.setflags(write=False)` but tried to do it in a way that is a bit more foolproof. To the implementation below the following 3 changes were made:

1. Copy the private attribute in the getter function to ensure that changing the flag of the public attribute does not change the flag of the private attribute.
2. The public attribute is set to non-writable to ensure that people are shown a warning if they try to set a slice of the attribute. (the protection works without this, but if someone sets your public attribute it will not throw an error, it will simply not do anything).
3. To ensure that the internal attribute is not writable.

```py
# Importing modules.
import numpy as np

class OurClass(object):
    """
    The class with an attribute that we want to protect.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
        The number of random numbers in the attribute.

    Attributes
    ----------
    our_attribute : array
        The attribute that contains `n` random numbers between 0 and 1, will never be smaller than zero.
    _our_attribute : array
        The protected attributed that ensures that `our_attribute` is never smaller then zero.
        (Normally I don't list this)
    """
    def __init__(self, n):
        # Set values to the attribute.
        self.our_attribute = np.random.random(n)

    @property
    def our_attribute(self):
        out = self._our_attribute.copy()  # --> Change 1
        out.setflags(write=False)  # --> Change 2
        return out

    @our_attribute.setter
    def our_attribute(self, value):
        """
        When the attribute is set, every entry needs to be larger then zero.

        Parameters
        ----------
        value : array
            The array that should replace our_attribute.
        """
        print("Setter function is used")
        self._our_attribute = np.clip(value, 0, np.inf)
        self._our_attribute.setflags(write=False)  # --> Change 3

# Lets create our object.
print('Create object:')
num = 5
our_object = OurClass(num)
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute, '\n')
```

Setting the entire attribute is still possible, but the attribute will be clipped appropriately.

```py
# Lets replace the setter function te verify that it works.
print('Change object:')
our_object.our_attribute = np.linspace(-5, 20, num)
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute, '\n')
```

Changing a slice of the array is not possible, it will through a `VallueError: assignment destination is read-only`.

```py
# Now modify a slice of the attribute, we can do this because it is a numpy array.
print('Modify a slice of the attribute.')
our_object.our_attribute[-1] = -5
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute)
```

Now someone could try to be 'smart' and change the write flag of the array that they obtained, but if they do so they won't influence the private attributed `self._our_attribute` as they obtained a deep copy from it, and every time that they call the public attribute they'll receive the copy again so the following will still through an error:

```py
# Now modify a slice of the attribute, we can do this because it is a numpy array.
print('Modify a slice of the attribute.')
our_object.our_attribute.setflags(write=True)
our_object.our_attribute[-1] = -5
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute)
```

The only way to circumvent this, without directly touching the private attribute, would be:

```py
# Now modify a slice of the copy of the attribute, at set the full attribute to the changed copy.
print('Modify a slice of the attribute.')
attribute = our_object.our_attribute.copy()
attribute[-1] = -5
our_object.our_attribute = attribute
print('  our_attribute:', our_object.our_attribute)
```

But this goes through our setter function again, exactly like we like it.